# Please help me identify my cactus

Tags: identification, cactus

Please help me identify my cactus :)

It is about 20 years old at about 3 feet tall.

[image: Cactus from a distance profile view]

It has 6-7 ribs near the top that fill out towards the middle and bottom.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjrZs.jpg) are some more closeup pictures showing the ribs of each arm and how they are more defined at the top and more filled out toward the middle and bottom.

I've tried a few online cactus identification tools, but maybe I'm using the wrong search terms because I can't seem to find anything that quite matches (as far as I can tell).

Comment: I learned this is a Blue Torch.